# Excel 2010 vba - Keep scrollbars in deactivated/inactive workbooks visible

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel (2010 and other) the workbook standard
scrollbars are only visible for the active
workbook. So if you have two or more workbooks
open only one shows scrollbars.

It looks as if the DisplayHorizontalScrollBar Property
applies only to:
`ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True`

Is there a way to keep the scrollbars of inactive
workbooks visible? Preferably with vba.

Comment: I dont use 2010 version to test it, but have you tried this? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-or-display-scroll-bars-in-a-workbook-2101e630-fa9b-4d22-90e0-b110278bafa7

Comment: Yes the scrollbars are enabled in the options, excel 2010. They only get hidden if you switch to another simultaneously open workbook.